# Subquery does not return results

Tags: sql-server-2008, subquery, case

I'm creating a large SELECT query that includes several sub-queries.  Each sub-query works fine, except one of them ('Tonnes/Metres').  I've used the same links and values as the others, however it does use different tables in a different database.  But the syntax looks correct to me, and if I pull the offending sub-select out and run it on its own, it works.

This is the TEST sub-select (with hard-coded parameters) that successfully returns one of the rows ...

```
  SELECT SUM((OreNo*CONVERT(decimal(10,2),ISNULL(round((Code1),2),0))) + (WasteNo*CONVERT(decimal(10,2),ISNULL(round((Code2),2),0))) + (WFG*CONVERT(decimal(10,2),ISNULL(round((Code3),2),0))))
  FROM BETA..Bogging, BETA..Equipment, OperationalAssetDetail
  WHERE EquipmentName = 'LD038' and
  OperationalAssetDetail.Name = EquipmentNameMainpac and
  BETA..Bogging.EquipmentID = BETA..Equipment.EquipmentID and
  '2013-01' = RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(year, Date) AS CHAR)) + '-' + right('0' + RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(month, Date) AS CHAR)),2)
```

... and this is the row it returns ...

(No column name)
33900.00

... but then I include it in the main query, and it returns null ...

```
declare @myAsset varchar(50)
set @myAsset = 'LD038'

select Name, months, 

ISNULL(
(
select CONVERT(decimal(10,2),ISNULL(round(ClassValue2,2),0))
from OperationalAssetDetail
where 
Name = @myAsset and 
SortKeyName = 1000 and
months >= RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(year, InstallDate) AS CHAR)) + '-' + right('0' + RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(month, InstallDate) AS CHAR)),2)  and
months <= RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(year, ExpiryDate) AS CHAR)) + '-' + right('0' + RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(month, ExpiryDate) AS CHAR)),2)
)
,0) as 'Ownership Cost',

(
select CONVERT(decimal(10,2),ISNULL(round(sum(AdditionalCost),2),0))
from Transactiondetail
where 
AccountStructureName like '%1625' and
OperationalAssetName = OperationalAssetDetail.Name and
ResourceName = 'Issue' and
months = RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(year, createtime) AS CHAR)) + '-' + right('0' + RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(month, createtime) AS CHAR)),2) 
) as 'Operating Cost',

(
select CONVERT(decimal(10,2),ISNULL(round(sum(AdditionalCost),2),0))
from Transactiondetail
where 
AccountStructureName like '%1627' and
OperationalAssetName = OperationalAssetDetail.Name and
ResourceName = 'Issue' and
months = RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(year, createtime) AS CHAR)) + '-' + right('0' + RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(month, createtime) AS CHAR)),2) 
) as 'Component Cost',

(
select CONVERT(decimal(10,2),ISNULL(round(sum(AdditionalCost),2),0))
from Transactiondetail
where 
AccountStructureName like '%1628' and
OperationalAssetName = OperationalAssetDetail.Name and
ResourceName = 'Issue' and
months = RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(year, createtime) AS CHAR)) + '-' + right('0' + RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(month, createtime) AS CHAR)),2) 
) as 'Tyre Cost',

(
select CONVERT(decimal(10,2),ISNULL(round(sum(AdditionalCost),2),0) + ClassValue2)
from Transactiondetail
where 
(AccountStructureName like '%1625' OR AccountStructureName like 'DM%1627' OR AccountStructureName like 'DM%1628') and
OperationalAssetName = OperationalAssetDetail.Name and
ResourceName = 'Issue' and
months = RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(year, createtime) AS CHAR)) + '-' + right('0' + RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(month, createtime) AS CHAR)),2) 
) as 'Total Cost',

CASE OperationalAssetDetail.Name 
WHEN 'DR%' THEN
      (
      select CONVERT(decimal(10,2),ISNULL(round(sum(Value),2),0))
      from UsageDetail
      where (OperationalAssetName LIKE OperationalAssetDetail.Name + '-07' OR OperationalAssetName LIKE OperationalAssetDetail.Name + '-08') and
      months = RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(year, createtime) AS CHAR)) + '-' + right('0' + RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(month, createtime) AS CHAR)),2) 
      )
WHEN 'LH%' THEN
      (
      select CONVERT(decimal(10,2),ISNULL(round(sum(Value),2),0))
      from UsageDetail
      where OperationalAssetName = OperationalAssetDetail.Name + '-08' and
      months = RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(year, createtime) AS CHAR)) + '-' + right('0' + RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(month, createtime) AS CHAR)),2) 
      )
ELSE
      (
      select CONVERT(decimal(10,2),ISNULL(round(sum(Value),2),0))
      from UsageDetail
      where OperationalAssetName = OperationalAssetDetail.Name and
      months = RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(year, createtime) AS CHAR)) + '-' + right('0' + RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(month, createtime) AS CHAR)),2) 
      )
END as 'Engine Hours',

CASE OperationalAssetDetail.Name 
WHEN 'LD%' THEN
      (
      SELECT SUM((OreNo*CONVERT(decimal(10,2),ISNULL(round((Code1),2),0))) + (WasteNo*CONVERT(decimal(10,2),ISNULL(round((Code2),2),0))) + (WFG*CONVERT(decimal(10,2),ISNULL(round((Code3),2),0))))
      FROM BETA..Bogging, BETA..Equipment, OperationalAssetDetail
      WHERE EquipmentName = @myAsset and
      OperationalAssetDetail.Name = EquipmentNameMainpac and
      BETA..Bogging.EquipmentID = BETA..Equipment.EquipmentID and
      months = RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(year, Date) AS CHAR)) + '-' + right('0' + RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(month, Date) AS CHAR)),2) 
      )            
END as 'Tonnes/Metres'

from months, OperationalAssetDetail
where 
Name = @myAsset and 
SortKeyName = 1000 and
months >= RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(year, InstallDate) AS CHAR)) + '-' + right('0' + RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(month, InstallDate) AS CHAR)),2)  and
months <= RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(year, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS CHAR)) + '-' + right('0' + RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(month, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS CHAR)),2)
```

... here are the results ...

```
Name    months  Ownership Cost  Operating Cost  Component Cost  Tyre Cost   Total Cost  Engine Hours    Tonnes/Metres
LD038   2010-08 45072.37    0.00    0.00    0.00    45072.37    0.00    NULL
LD038   2010-09 45072.37    0.00    0.00    0.00    45072.37    0.00    NULL
LD038   2010-10 45072.37    0.00    0.00    0.00    45072.37    0.00    NULL
LD038   2010-11 45072.37    0.00    0.00    0.00    45072.37    0.00    NULL
LD038   2010-12 45072.37    0.00    0.00    0.00    45072.37    0.00    NULL
LD038   2011-01 45072.37    0.00    0.00    0.00    45072.37    0.00    NULL
LD038   2011-02 45072.37    0.00    0.00    0.00    45072.37    0.00    NULL
LD038   2011-03 45072.37    0.00    0.00    0.00    45072.37    0.00    NULL
LD038   2011-04 45072.37    0.00    0.00    0.00    45072.37    0.00    NULL
LD038   2011-05 45072.37    0.00    0.00    0.00    45072.37    0.00    NULL
LD038   2011-06 45072.37    0.00    0.00    0.00    45072.37    0.00    NULL
LD038   2011-07 45072.37    0.00    0.00    0.00    45072.37    0.00    NULL
LD038   2011-08 45072.37    0.00    0.00    0.00    45072.37    0.00    NULL
LD038   2011-09 45072.37    0.00    0.00    0.00    45072.37    0.00    NULL
LD038   2011-10 45072.37    0.00    0.00    0.00    45072.37    0.00    NULL
LD038   2011-11 45072.37    0.00    0.00    0.00    45072.37    0.00    NULL
LD038   2011-12 45072.37    0.00    0.00    0.00    45072.37    0.00    NULL
LD038   2012-01 45072.37    0.00    0.00    0.00    45072.37    0.00    NULL
LD038   2012-02 45072.37    0.00    0.00    0.00    45072.37    0.00    NULL
LD038   2012-03 45072.37    0.00    0.00    0.00    45072.37    0.00    NULL
LD038   2012-04 45072.37    0.00    0.00    0.00    45072.37    0.00    NULL
LD038   2012-05 45072.37    0.00    0.00    0.00    45072.37    0.00    NULL
LD038   2012-06 45072.37    0.00    0.00    0.00    45072.37    0.00    NULL
LD038   2012-07 45072.37    0.00    0.00    0.00    45072.37    0.00    NULL
LD038   2012-08 45072.37    0.00    0.00    0.00    45072.37    7659.00 NULL
LD038   2012-09 45072.37    839.49  0.00    0.00    45911.86    191.00  NULL
LD038   2012-10 45072.37    2817.43 0.00    20382.67    68272.47    488.00  NULL
LD038   2012-11 45072.37    3103.25 0.00    0.00    48175.62    358.00  NULL
LD038   2012-12 45072.37    1322.96 0.00    0.00    46395.33    461.00  NULL
LD038   2013-01 45072.37    23346.40    0.00    0.00    68418.77    225.00  NULL
LD038   2013-02 45072.37    507.58  0.00    0.00    45579.95    0.00    NULL
```

Comment: Well for one please stop doing all this cast to string nonsense: `RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(month, Date)`

Answer (score 1):

I dont see an ELSE statement on the CASE statment for Tones/Metres. Try adding the **ELSE** statement and see if it returns the else value, then you know your condition isn't working quite right.

> (This would be the OperationalAssetDetail.Name != 'LD%' )

Try this as the case and see if 'Wenis' is returned, if it is you know your case condition is not working.

```
CASE OperationalAssetDetail.Name WHEN 'LD%' THEN ( SELECT SUM((OreNo*CONVERT(decimal(10,2),ISNULL(round((Code1),2),0))) + (WasteNo*CONVERT(decimal(10,2),ISNULL(round((Code2),2),0))) + (WFG*CONVERT(decimal(10,2),ISNULL(round((Code3),2),0)))) FROM BETA..Bogging, BETA..Equipment, OperationalAssetDetail WHERE EquipmentName = @myAsset and OperationalAssetDetail.Name = EquipmentNameMainpac and BETA..Bogging.EquipmentID = BETA..Equipment.EquipmentID and months = RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(year, Date) AS CHAR)) + '-' + right('0' + RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(month, Date) AS CHAR)),2) )
ELSE 0
END as 'Tonnes/Metres'
```

Also for debugging add

```
OperationalAssetDetail.Name
```

As one of the column results to visually see what it is.

This select needs a **LOT** of work.

Comment: select * from Months

Months
2010-01
2010-02
2010-03
2010-04
2010-05
2010-06
2010-07
2010-08
2010-09
2010-10
2010-11
2010-12
2011-01
2011-02
2011-03
2011-04
2011-05
2011-06
2011-07
2011-08
2011-09
2011-10
2011-11
2011-12
2012-01
2012-02
2012-03
2012-04
2012-05
2012-06
2012-07
2012-08
2012-09
2012-10
2012-11
2012-12
2013-01
2013-02
2013-03
2013-04
2013-05
2013-06
2013-07
2013-08
2013-09
2013-10
2013-11
2013-12
2014-01
2014-02
2014-03
2014-04
2014-05
2014-06
2014-07
2014-08
2014-09
2014-10
2014-11
2014-12
2015-01
2015-02
2015-03
2015-04
2015-05
2015-06
2015-07
2015-08
2015-09
2015-10

Comment: Hmmm, when I add the ELSE statement I get all ZEROS instead of NULLS, so it seems the SELECT is never getting processed.  That helps, thanks!

ELSE
   0       
END as 'Tonnes/Metres'

Comment: Yup just as I suspected. Add the column OperationalAssettDetail.Name to see what its value is. Then you can accept my answer anytime!